# adding blank lines in a for loop java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, lines

```
public class XO {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        for(int i=1;i<=6;i++)
        {
            for(int j=1;j<=i;j++)
            {
                System.out.print("O");
            }
            for(int k=6;k>=i; k--)
            {
                System.out.print("X");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }   
    }
}
```

The above method prints this:

```
OXXXXXX
OOXXXXX
OOOXXXX
OOOOXXX
OOOOOXX
OOOOOOX
```

But I need it to produce this and can't figure it out

```
OXXXXXX

OOXXXXX

OOOXXXX

OOOOXXX

OOOOOXX

OOOOOOX
```

Basically, adding a blank line between the lines.

Answer (score 6):

Just use an extra call to `println()` whenever you need a blank line.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    for(int i=1;i<=6;i++)
    {
        for(int j=1;j<=i;j++)
        {
            System.out.print("O");
        }
        for(int k=6;k>=i; k--)
        {
            System.out.print("X");
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

You will need to add a bit more logic if it's important to suppress the extra blank line at the end.

Comment: Just using `System.out.println("\n");` should work as well, I guess?

Comment: @Yashovardhan - Most of the time, yes. But as Elliott Frisch suggests in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46518254/535871), it should be `System.out.println(System.lineSeparator())` (or, prior to Java 7, `System.out.println(System.getProperty("line.separator"))`). The newline character (`"\n"`) is not the line separator on all systems.

Comment: oh, I didn't know that `"\n"` was actually system dependent. Thanks for this! I was also not aware of `System.lineSeperator();` before yesterday when I read his answer! Thanks once again!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you, just change the `println()` to print two lines. Change,

```
System.out.println();
```

to something like

```
System.out.println(System.lineSeparator());
```

**or** just

```
System.out.println();
System.out.println();
```

You could also replace all of those nested loops with a single loop if you use two `StringBuilder`(s) to hold the X and O characters. Like,

```
StringBuilder xs = new StringBuilder("XXXXXX");
StringBuilder os = new StringBuilder("O");
while (xs.length() > 0) {
    System.out.printf("%s%s%n%n", os, xs); //<-- you can also use printf
                                           //    this prints two String(s)
                                           //    and then two lines.
    xs.setLength(xs.length() - 1);
    os.append("O");
}
```

Comment: Note that `System.lineSeparator()` is not available until Java 7. Prior to that, you would need to use `System.getProperty("line.separator")` (and you would probably want to stash it in a local variable or field to avoid the look-up overhead on every loop).

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i=1;i<=6;i++)
{
    for(int j=1;j<=i;j++)
    {
        System.out.print("O");
    }
    for(int k=6;k>=i; k--)
    {
        System.out.print("X");
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: As pointed by Ted Hopp in a comment to [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46518256/7252861), `"\n"` may not work as a line seperator on all systems. So the answer below is not valid everywhere.

Just replace

```
//Your code
System.out.println();
//Remaining code
```

With

```
//Some code
System.out.println("\n");
//some code
```

`println()` prints a newline character (i.e. takes you to the next line) after printing anything that's within. `\n` is the representation of the newline character. In your code, after every loop, the `println()` function takes the control to the next line but not leaving a line in between. An extra `\n` will take the control to 2 lines following it. I.e. leave a line in between. The same can be accomplished by

```
//Previous code
System.out.print("\n\n");
//Remaining code
```

As well. Or you can use two `println()` statements successively as demonstrated in other answers. Choose whatever suits you.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to put extra blank print statement.

```
public class XO {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        for(int i=1;i<=6;i++)
        {
            for(int j=1;j<=i;j++)
            {
                System.out.print("O");
            }
            for(int k=6;k>=i; k--)
            {
                System.out.print("X");
            }
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println();
        }   
    }
}
```

Here, `System.out.print("O");` and `System.out.print("X");` lines doesn't go to a new line after printing the value. so we have to put a blank print statement inside the outer loop. To ave blank line between each printed line. we have to put another blank print statement.